# How to compare 2^sqrt(lg (n^2)) and 4^(lg (n))

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I do not want a solution just some guidance.

I think 2^sqrt(lg (n^2)) = O(4^lg(n)).

However I am lost as how I can show proof.  Is there a formula or property that will get me going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First I would start by trying to simplify your run time. Is there a property that tells us how roots and powers interact when used in conjunction, or how powers within logs can be simplified.